# How to send SOAP request to ONVIF IP Camera using C++ and libcurl?

Tags: c++, soap, soap-client, ip-camera, onvif

Below is how I have tried in C++.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>

struct MemoryStruct {
    char *memory;
    size_t size;
};

int main()
{
    std::string pstFld = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV=\"http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope\" xmlns:tds=\"http://www.onvif.org/ver10/device/wsdl\"><SOAP-ENV:Body><tds:GetSystemDateAndTime/></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>";
    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode res;

    struct MemoryStruct chunk;
    chunk.memory = (char *) malloc(1);
    chunk.size = 0;

    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);
    curl = curl_easy_init();

    if (curl)
    {
        struct curl_slist *slist = NULL;
        slist = curl_slist_append(slist, "Host: my_ip_address");
        slist = curl_slist_append(slist, "Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8");
        std::string contentLength = "Content-Length: " + std::to_string(pstFld.size());
        slist = curl_slist_append(slist, contentLength.c_str());
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://my_ip_address/onvif/device_service");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, pstFld);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, slist);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, WriteMemoryCallback);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, (void *) &chunk);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "libcurl-agent/1.0");

        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

        if (res != CURLE_OK)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed: %s\n", curl_easy_strerror(res));
        }
        else
        {
            printf("%lu bytes retrieved.\n", (unsigned long) chunk.size);
        }

        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
        curl = NULL;
    }

    free(chunk.memory);
    curl_global_cleanup();

    return 0;
}
```

Below is the message from the `curl_easy_strerror(res)`.

```
* upload completely sent off: 6 out of 6 bytes
* Empty reply from server
Failed: Server returned nothing (no headers, no data)
```

What do I need to do to get the response data from ONVIF?

Note that I could successfully send SOAP request to the same ONVIF IP Camera using PHP CURL and get the XML response as well, but with C++ I could send the request but I got no response.

Comment: Probably unrelated, but don't you need a `SOAPAction` header?  Also, I am pretty sure a `Host` header is necessary.

Comment: Does your device definitely support SOAP 1.1 ?  That `Content-Type` header is only used by SOAP 1.1.

Comment: I have added `Host` header, I got no error but no results as well. Only this `* Operation timed out after 10001 milliseconds with 0 bytes received * Closing connection 0`. I think that device supports SOAP 1.1.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have found the solution.

```
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <iostream>

static size_t handleResponse(void *contents, size_t length, size_t nmemb, void *userp)
{
     ((std::string*)userp)->append((char*)contents, length * nmemb);
     return length * nmemb;
}

int main()
{
    std::string readBuffer;
    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode res;
    std::string postField = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><s:Envelope xmlns:s=\"http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope\"><s:Body xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\"><GetSystemDateAndTime xmlns=\"http://www.onvif.org/ver10/device/wsdl\" /></s:Body></s:Envelope>";
    curl = curl_easy_init();

    if (curl)
    {
        struct curl_slist *slist = NULL;
        slist = curl_slist_append(slist, "Accept: */*");
        slist = curl_slist_append(slist, "Content-Type: text/xml");
        std::string content_length = "Content-Length: " + std::to_string(postField.size());

        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, slist);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://my_ip_address/onvif/device_service");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, postField.c_str());
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, handleResponse);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &readBuffer);
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

        if (res != CURLE_OK)
        {
            std::cout << "Failed." << std::endl;
        }

        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
        curl_slist_free_all(slist);
    }

    return 0;
}
```